# Converting minutes to hours only

Tags: c#, timespan

I’m trying to solve this problem :

I’ve a large amount of minutes and I want to convert them into hours only, when I try with `TimeSpan`, it always shows days and hours.

My example code :

```
double minutes = 2000 ;
TimeSpan hours = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
label1.Text = hours.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

The output result is  **09:20**  but I wanted  this result **33:20**

How can I convert minutes to get exact numbers of hours ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code produces the `33:20` result you're asking:

```
double minutes = 2000;
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
var res = $"{(int)ts.TotalHours}:{ts.Minutes}";
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `TotalHours` on the `TimeSpan` object.

```
string.Format("{0}:{1}",
    (int) hours.TotalHours,
    hours.Minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility is to use `0` and `00` formatting strings in order to combine *formatting* and *truncating*:

```
double minutes = 2000;

// 2000 -> 33:20
// 1808 -> 30:08
//    8 -> 0:08
label1.Text = $"{minutes/60:0}:{minutes%60:00}";
```

If `minutes` can be *negative*, you should add `Math.Abs`:

```
// -2000 -> -33:20
label1.Text = $"{minutes/60:0}:{Math.Abs(minutes)%60:00}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it manually and use

```
string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}",(int)minutes/60, (int)minutes%60)
```

or without casting:

```
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes/60, minutes%60)
```

Since C#6 with String Interpolation:

```
$"{minutes/60:00}:{minutes%60:00}"
```

Comment: This gives `Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Format specifier was invalid.`

Comment: Just use `string.Format("{0}:{1}",(int)minutes/60, minutes%60)` or `$"{(int)minutes/60}:{minutes%60}"`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: The exception can be fixed by casting the result. Found this here [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) __D -- Supported by: Integral types only.__  So this should work with `string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}",(int)minutes/60, (int)minutes%60)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
{
    //assigning values to variable
    double minutes = 2000;
    TimeSpan tspan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes); //converting minutes to timespan
    string res1 = (int)tspan.TotalHours +" Hours " + tspan.Minutes +" Minutes"; 

    string res2= (int)tspan.TotalHours + ":"+tspan.Minutes; 

    string res3= Convert.ToInt32(tspan.TotalHours)  + "."+tspan.Minutes +" Hours"; 

    Console.WriteLine(res1);
    Console.WriteLine(res2);
    Console.WriteLine(res3);
}
```

Output:

```
33 Hours 20 Minutes
33:20
33.20 Hours
```